# django not returning any value for .id or .pk

Tags: django, django-models

I am just following one of the Django tutorials verbatim and have encountered a problem with queries of `x.id` or `.pk` not returning any value at all. This is across all rows in that table, though all other data is working. An example below is taken from my python shell.

```
>>> c = Album(artist="Stone Roses", album_title="The Stone Roses", genre="Indie", album_logo="http://www.classicrockreview.com/Images/1989/AlbumCovers/1989_StoneRos    es.jpg")

>>> c
<Album: Album object>
>>> c.id
>>> c.artist
'Stone Roses'
>>> c.pk
>>>
```

I was led to believe that `id` is automatically taken care of by Django?

Comment: Did you save the object before checking for the id?

Comment: I did, this was just tapped in as an example. Tried wiping and starting a whole new DB and same thing.

Comment: Here is what I get from trying to save properly:      
>>> a = Album(artist="Oasis", album_title="Definitely Maybe", genre="Indie", album_logo="none") >>> a.save <bound method Model.save of <Album: Definitely Maybe - Oasis - Indie>> >>> – user8467470 3 mins ago   edit

Comment: Sorry - I am a MORON! I forgot the parenthesis on save

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `Album` object is not currently saved to the database so it has no `id` yet. You need to call `object.save()` in order to do that:

```
>>> c = Album(...)
>>> c.id      # Object is not yet saved to the database so it has no id
None
>>> c.save()  # Save object to the database
>>> c.id      # Object's valid id
```

*See the [Django model instance reference docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/instances/#auto-incrementing-primary-keys) for more detailed explanation.*

Comment: Thanks - I hadn't on that one but had on a and b which I could call on other than a.id b.id etc

Comment: Ah, I just noticed the following message from the save:

Comment: >>> a = Album(artist="Oasis", album_title="Definitely Maybe", genre="Indie", album_logo="none")
>>> a.save
<bound method Model.save of <Album: Definitely Maybe - Oasis - Indie>>
>>>

Comment: Sorry - I am a MORON! I forgot the parenthesis on save